# Populate input field when button is clicked

Tags: angular

I have an *ngFor looping through a bunch of listings. I'm trying to have it so that when a user clicks the buy it now price, it autofills the input field with the buy it now price so that the user only has to hit submit. The challenge I'm facing is I'm trying to use `let i = index` to figure out which listing has been clicked, but it throws an error when adding let i = index to ngFor like so

`*ngFor="let auction of posts | let i = index|  paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count }">`

It's fine like this though

`*ngFor="let auction of posts |  paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count }">`

but let index = i doesn't play nice with paginate code. My question is how to get the index working with paginate code and how I can use it to populate the input field for that specific row?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>

  <body [ngClass]="[(this.isOpen && this.mobile) || (this.isOpen && this.tablet) ? 'hideContent' : 'showContent']">
    <div class="loading">
      <!-- <mat-spinner class="loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner> -->

      <ngx-spinner id="loadingIcon" *ngIf="isLoading" type="cog" size="medium" color="#3071a9">
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <p class="loadingTitle">Loading...</p>
      </ngx-spinner>
    </div>
    <div class="spacing"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="paginator"></div>
        <ngb-pagination
          (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"
          [collectionSize]="this.totalPosts"
          *ngIf="!this.mobile && this.totalPosts"
          [(page)]="this.currentPage"
          [boundaryLinks]="true"
        ></ngb-pagination>

        <ngb-pagination
          (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"
          [collectionSize]="120"
          [(page)]="this.currentPage || this.totalPosts"
          *ngIf="this.mobile && this.totalPosts"
          [maxSize]="5"
          [rotate]="true"
          [ellipses]="false"
          [boundaryLinks]="true"
        ></ngb-pagination>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="row no-gutters"
      *ngIf="(!this.isOpen && this.mobile) || (this.isOpen && !this.mobile) || (!this.isOpen && !this.mobile)"
    ></div>
    <!--; let i = index-->
    <div
      class="row"
      *ngFor="let listing of posts | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count }"
    >
      <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">
        <div class="listingCard" [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">
          <li>
            Buy it Now: <span id="buyItNowStatus" (click)="buyItNow(listing, i)">{{ listing.buyItNow }}</span>
          </li>

          <div class="row"></div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div id="title">{{ listing.Title }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
              <img
                class="image"
                src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/dfd/7290/products/IMPERIAL_NEW1.jpg?v=1565307462"
                (click)="openImageGallery()"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5">
              <br />
              <ul class="info">
                <li>
                  <div id="bidding">
                    <!--Starting Bid-->

                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formFields">
                      <mat-label id="placeholder">Enter Bid</mat-label>

                      <input
                        matInput
                        name="bidInput"
                        type="text"
                        ngModel
                        required
                        [value]="this.buyItNow"
                        #bidInput="ngModel"
                        pattern="^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|0)?\.\d{2}$"
                      />
                      <mat-error>Dollar Format 00:00 or 0:00</mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>

                    <button id="auctionButton" mat-raised-button (click)="confirmPurchase(bidInput.value)">
                      Submit Bid
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
  buyItNow(listing: []) {
    this.buyItNowPrice = listing["buyItNow"];
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pipe your index, that won't work. Change this:

`*ngFor="let auction of posts | let i = index|  paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count }">`

to

`*ngFor="let auction of posts | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count };index as i">`

**For your second question**

In your `app.component.ts`, add id to each element in your array and update your `buyItNow` function as shown.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  buyItNowPrice;
   posts = [{"id": 0 ,"buyItNow": "12:00", "title": "title 1"}, {
      "id": 1 ,"buyItNow": "22:00", "title": "title 2"
    }, {"id": 2 ,"buyItNow": "32:00", "title": "title 3"}];


  buyItNow(listing: any) {
    this.buyItNowPrice = listing["buyItNow"];
    let x = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('listing' + listing.id));
    x.value = listing.buyItNow;
  }
 }
```

In `app.component.html`, add id to your `<input>` tag to uniquely identify each input.

```
<input
  id = 'listing{{i}}'
  name="bidInput"
  type="text"
  ngModel
  required
  [value]="this.buyItNow"
  #bidInput="ngModel"
  pattern="^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|0)?\.\d{2}$"/>
```

Comment: That makes sense and that part is working now. Thanks! Any chance you know how I can get the buy it now price for that specific row to appear in the input field onClick?

Comment: Could you provide a Stackblitz for it, and I can have a look. Also, it would be great if you marked this as the correct answer.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ut4f2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look

Comment: I added your solution, but it was missing ```(click)="buyItNow(auction)``` I added that, but nothing happens when I click the buy it now price. https://pastebin.com/qwVnSA8x

Comment: I got it working by changing id = 'listing{{id}} to id = 'listing-${auction.id} and then let x = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("listing-" + listing.id); mat-form-field isn't registering that the value exists within it's field even though it's in the correct format and everything. I think it's related to using DOM, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to declare the 'index' property into the pipe chain. This will fix it:

```
*ngFor="let listing of posts | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count }, index as i"
```

Also to update only the input for the current post, i would recommend another 'Approach'. Because already have a reference to the original 'listing' object inside the 'for' loop, you may try to set the `buyItNowPrice` as another property in this object and link it as the ngModel from the input node.

As this way, only the (now called) `CurrentBidPrice` prop included in the current 'Listing' will be used to update the value on the input.

```
buyItNow(listing: any) {
    listing.currentBid = listing.buyItNow;
}

<input 
    matInput 
    name="bidInput" 
    type="text" 
    [(ngModel)]="listing.currentBid" 
    required 
    #bidInput="ngModel" 
    pattern="^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|0)?\.\d{2}$" />
```

I attach a Stackblitz with an example of the concept.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nccdtw

Comment: This works better. I can edit the field after I click the value, but the only issue is that currentBid will have a value. So when I load the page, the input field is populated with the currentBid value instead of being a blank field in your example until the buy it now value is clicked. What could I do to make that not happen? Another thing that happens on click is the current bid label value gets overwritten by buy it now value.  ```Current Bid: {{auction.currentBid}}```

Comment: You can listen the `pageChange` event to clear the `currentBid` prop setted by clicking the value. Also to avoid changes after set some value on the input manually, you can do a check in the`buyItNow` method. I updated the Stackblitz workspace with the concept.

Comment: Here's your solution + I added another <li> to demonstrate what I mean when you click buy it now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhrpqc

Comment: Ok i see, in that case is possible to initialize `currentBid` in the constructor with the default values and reset the inputs to this values when you update the paginator, all this, calling to a common method for both. I updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nccdtw) with a `resetBids` method to achieve this.

Comment: In this example, the currentBid and buy it now are the same price. I'm not trying to replace the currentBid price. The only thing I want to do is populate the buyItNow value when clicked into the input field. currentBid shouldn't be changed at all. So buy it now could be $300. and current bid could be $40. That value never changes from $40. Only input field gets populated and that's it. Also all input fields should be blank on page load.

Comment: In the example, `currentBid` is just a model linked to the input field value. It will always change when someone type into the input field or click on the 'Buy It Now' label. I put back the 'blank field on load' behaviour.